# How to rotate an UIWebView embedded video

Tags: iphone, objective-c, video, uiwebview, rotation

So I have this problem with an application I am building that I can't figure out.
My application has the following structure:

> UITabBarController -> UIViewController -> UIViewController

The last view controller contains an UIWebView which loads an entire page. In that page there is a movie (mp4) that users can play once they hit the big round play button.

The application is made such that it runs in portrait mode, and there is no way I can do it run otherwise because of it's initial design.

What I want to achieve is let users rotate their phones once the movie starts playing and rotate the movie accordingly. I've managed to 'detect' when the movie is played by listening to different NSNotifications that NSNotificationsCenter sends.

I used this for detecting the start:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
selector:@selector(movieIsPlaying:)
name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerDidEnterFullscreenNotification"
object:nil];
```

and this for detecting the end:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
selector:@selector(movieStopedPlaying:)
name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerDidExitFullscreenNotification"
object:nil];
```

With the 2 selectors now I set one global variable to YES or NO which I can use later in

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
```

If I always return YES from the above method my application interface rotates on every screen except when the movie is up and running. The weirdest thing is this:

- I open the application in portrait.
- Go to the desired page (see my structure above)
- Rotate the phone to landscape (the interface rotates - this is just for debugging)
- I start the movie (it launches in landscape! Hooray!)
- I rotate the phone back to portrait (the movie rotates! Hooray again!)
- I rotate the phone back to landscape (no more rotation occurs...)

Also if I start the movie in portrait mode it will never rotate.

**Update**

In the end I've come up with this solution for the 2 methods mentioned above:

```
- (void)movieIsPlaying:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if (![Globals canRotateInterface]) {
        [Globals setCanRotateInterface:YES];
        
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight animated:NO];
                
        [[[[notification object] view] window] setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)];
        [[[[notification object] view] window] setCenter:CGPointMake(160, 240)];
        [[[[notification object] view] window] setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2)];
    }
}

- (void)movieStopedPlaying:(NSNotification *)notification
{   
    if ([Globals canRotateInterface]) {
        [Globals setCanRotateInterface:NO];
        
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait animated:NO];
        
        [[[[notification object] view] window] setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
        [[[[notification object] view] window] setTransform:CGAffineTransformIdentity];
                    
        // Little hack to force an orientation rotation so that all elements get their original size and place (eg. Navigation bar)
        UINavigationController *dummyNavigationViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
        [self presentModalViewController:dummyNavigationViewController animated:NO];
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
        [dummyNavigationViewController release];
    }
}
```

Comment: How can we play it on iOS 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did in the end was use the 2 mentioned notifications to detect when the user plays or stops the movie and have code that rotates the window to 90 degrees. This way the user only sees the movie in landscape mode but it's better than just seeing it in portrait.

Answer (score 0):

You should try implementing shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation by just returning the fullScreen property of the MoviePlayerController, rather than catching notifications for entering / exiting fullscreen mode : I suspect rotations can cause a little mess in these notifications.

Comment: The thing is I don't have access to the MoviePlayerController because I don't create it myself. As I said the movie is embedded in an UIWebView and when an user starts playing it the OS automatically creates a player and displays it on-top of the application. If I don't use those notifications there is no way to know if the movie is playing or not... Any other suggestion? Or do you have any idea how I can debug it so I can find which controller returns NO to the autorotate function?

Comment: Ok sorry, I'm not really used to UIWebView since the unique iOS project I'm working on doesn't use any. Btw, I was wondering how the presented MoviePlayerController could be accessed, even if presented by system, and just had a little idea, but I've no time now for testing further, so here's the idea : in your shouldAutoRotateBlabla implementation, could you try to use NavigationController's VisibleViewController or ModalViewController properties to test their type against MoviePlayerViewController? If one of them match, MoviePlayerViewController.MoviePlayer.Fullscreen should make you happy :)